# Detect if html Element is created using external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, web, browser, frontend

i would like to know if there is any method in  JavaScript that we can detect if any node(Html Element) was created from the external JS file.
For example many time we use the external js file using script tag  then that script creates some element on our page (example chat bots and ifrmae ) i would like to detect if any  html node was created using external js file or from our internal or self hosted js file.

Comment: Not unless the created element has a specific property added by the external script (or lacks a property added to all elements on the original document).

Comment: If some library adds an element to the DOM, it probably has a class. You could check what that class name is and search for it with this: [HTML DOM getElementsByClassName() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Comment: @Jesper there could be multiple scripts and they can create element with any  class or other attributes

Comment: You can do this using a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I've put an example below. It's worth mentioning that it can be quite an expensive operation on a complicated page though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for this.

A Mutation Observer can be set up to watch a specific element, and provides a callback function for any changes to it. This includes the addition of nodes, changes to attributes, [and more](https://javascript.info/mutation-observer).

If you run your observer before any other scripts on your page you'll be able to know if something has been changed by a subsequent script, as long as the parent node exists.

This is a basic example that observes when a list element has something added to it:

```js
let animals = document.getElementById('animals');
let add = document.getElementById('add');
options = {
    childList: true
  },
  observer = new MutationObserver(onChanged);

function onChanged(mutations) {
  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    // specify which type of mutation you want to observe
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('a list item has been added');
    }
  }
}

observer.observe(animals, options);

add.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("New item"));
  animals.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id="animals" class="list">
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Guinea Pig</li>
  <li>Rabbit</li>
</ul>

<button id="add">Add to list</button>
```